# Jenkins return value from catch block

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I have a scripted jenkins pipeline with the code like this.

```
value=true
fun_stage_1()
println +value

def func_stage_1() {
    try {
        stage1{
              stage1 steps
                     } 
      }
   catch {
           value=false
           return value    
        }
}
```

Here I am expecting the value to be false in case of issues after calling the function , But it comes true. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of a variable inside a function is only valid inside the function but not outside.. So if you want to override it you need to do `value = func_stage_1()`

This is working for me, if the "try" not succeed the function will return false:

```
def value = true
def func_stage_1() {
    try {
        echo "test"
     } catch (err) {
           value=false    
     }
    return value

}

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages{
        stage ('test'){
            steps{
                script{
                    value = func_stage_1()
                    echo "${value}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is my implementaion wrong? any problem there? it always returns true

Comment: hoo i think i know check my answer edited please

Comment: still it prints true only

Comment: and what if you set `value=true` the first time in the function ? not at the top

Comment: not sure why the value is true even when I am setting it to false and returning it

Comment: are you sure that the try is not working ?

Comment: ofcourse. I am printing a message also inside to check that. Its coming to catch,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247335/discussion-between-mickael-rahmine-and-user2636464).